# Java - How to know if specific method is running at current moment

Tags: java

I have 2 web Application: Application1 and Application2 - both REST Application.

Application1 sometime call method in Application2.

This is very impotant part - only one instance of this method should run simultaneously. 
So before call method in Application2 from Application1 additional request is invoked to test if method is running at current moment on not.

Now I achive it this way (it is not actual code - this is just to show roughly what actual code do):

```
static Boolean ifRunning = false;

static void methodWrapper() throws Exception {

    try {
        ifRunning = true;
        method();
    } finally {
        ifRunning = false;
    }
}

static void method() {
    // do something
}

static Boolean monitorMethod() {
    return ifRunning;
}
```

In this code:

- "method" - only one instance of this method should run simultaneously
- "monitorMethod" - this method that is used to monitoring

It is not the best solution: "finally" in "methodWrapper" may not execute (there is some cases - for example with System.exit(0)), so at some moment "ifRunning" can remain true at the end of method. As a result starting from that moment Application1 whould think that method alway running.

So is there a better solution for my goal?

Comment: Can you share your usecase? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm guessing your code would be multithreaded.  Please add a description to what your program is supposed to be doing.

Comment: If you call `System.exit` - then who cares

Comment: if you call System.exit(0) in method(), not only your method stops but also your jvm is down.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your code as it stands is that it won't work correctly if called from multiple threads: there is no guarantee that other threads will see the "correct" value of `running`.

You can use a `Semaphore`:

```
static final Semaphore running = new Semaphore(1);

static void methodWrapper() throws Exception {
    if (!running.tryAcquire()) {
        throw new Exception("Already running!!!");
    }
    try {
        method();
    } finally {
        running.release();
    }
}
```

The disadvantage of `Semaphore` is that you can't query it to see if something is running. Instead, you could use `AtomicBoolean`:

```
static final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean();

static void methodWrapper() throws Exception {
    if (!running.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        throw new Exception("Already running!!!");
    }
    try {
        method();
    } finally {
        running.set(false);
    }
}
```

Now you get largely the same behavior as with the semaphore, but you can call `running.get()` to see if anything is running the method at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to care for `System.exit`. After that, your application stops anyway. So why care whether the method ran before.

I take it, that the problem is not a recursion issue. So you do have a problem because your code is not thread-safe! You have to either synchronize every access to isRunning or make it volatile. I'd suggest `private volatile boolean` (primitive boolean!).

Comment: `volatile` would not make that method thread-safe, because two threads could do `if` check in parallel, then both call `method()`, *in parallel*.

Comment: @Andreas You're right, of course. It has to be completely synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Callback functions will be useful to notify before System.exit(0).

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method(() -> {
            System.out.println("System.exit() will be called!");
        });
        System.out.println("System.exit() did not called!");
    }

    private static void method(Callback callback) {
        if (Math.random() * 10 > 5) {
            callback.notifySystemExit();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("JVM is saved!");
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Callback {
    void notifySystemExit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally you can get Current Thread's stack trace to get details of current executed method.

`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` will usually contain the method currently executing but there are pitfalls.

See Java Docs:[Stack Trace Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace)

Comment: OP *"wants to monitor if [method] runs at current moment"*. By any definition I can think of, "monitoring" implies from outside the thread.

Comment: Cant I get to match my method name from stack trace??